# How to mock the same module twice in the same test with Jest and React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'd like to know if there is a way to change the return value of a mock after a react component is rendered.

I have a named export module called useUser (shown below) that returns the user authentication state from firebase.

```
  export const useUser = () => {
    return useAuthState(authenticated);
  };
```

I have a React app with pages that uses the useUser to check if user is authenticated and in case the user is not authenticated, redirect the page to the login page ('/'), otherwise, keep the user on the page and do other things. I did this algorithm using useEffect, as below:

```
  const [user, loading] = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    if (!user) nav('/');
    if(user) doSomething();
  }, [user]);
```

When testing, I mock the module to return `[false, false]` (user not authenticated) or `[true, false]` (user authenticated) and it works fine.
I coded the test like this:

```
  jest.mock('assets/state/hooks/firebaseHooks', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('assets/state/hooks/firebaseHooks'),
    useUser: jest.fn()
  }));
  
  it('should stay in this page when user loggedin', () => {
    (useUser as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce([true, false]);
    render(
      <RecoilRoot>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <AddCategory />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </RecoilRoot>
    );

    expect(mockedNavegacao).not.toBeCalled();
  });
```

Now, when the Jest renders the `<AddCategory />` component, the mocked value is `[true, false]`.
I would like to test the behavior of changing this returned value to `[false, false]`, like the `fireEvent.change` does with inputs.
Is there anyway to do it?

The user state does not change with a user action is this component. It changes with a user action in another component where user can sign out, and this `<AddCategory />` component only gets the state and redirect the page accordingly. So that is the reason I could not think of a way of doing this with `fireEvent`.

I tried chaining the `mockReturnValue`.

```
  (useUser as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce([true, false]).mockReturnValueOnce([false,false]);
```

But inside the component, the `useUser()` is called just once, so only the first return is taken.

Any ideias?

Comment: Why not render it again, in a different test, to test this different case?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it would be a different situation. What I'd really like to test is.
1. user authenticated
2. page renders
3. user signs out (there is an action here that changes the user state)
4. page automatically redirect to Login page

I understand that rendering it again with the other value would be something different like
1. user is not authenticated since beginning
2. page renders and automatically redirects to Login page

Comment: But that's not all the responsibility of the component you're testing. All it does is call the hook when it renders then show the appropriate thing.

Comment: I understand it is not the responsibility of this component the action of signing out.
But it is the responsibility of this component to keep track of the user state, and in case it changes, to redict the user to the Login page.

Comment: Let me try to explain a bug. If I do what you said, and change the return of the mock and render the component again, the test would pass. But it would also pass for the code bellow.
`useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    if (!user) nav('/');
    if(user) doSomething();
  }, []);`
This code would work for the first render. But it is wrong, because it wouldnt keep track of the user state.